# Payment methods Norway (euro)

Tags: payment-cards, norway, euro

I'm Dutch and i'll be traveling to a friend in Norway who just became a father. 
I'll be staying there for just the Saturday and Sunday. Am i able to pay using euro's with a dutch debit card (Rabobank) or would it be wiser to exchange some money.

It will only be for a one night hotel stay, dinner and possibly public transportation.

Comment: I did not spent almost any of the cash I had with me. My contactless VISA debit (not credit) card was preferred way of payment everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the cards are accepted around Europe. It will make an own calculation of the courses for the Norwegian Crowns to Euros when you make a transaction.

Do you have a credit card? Hotels might ask for a credit card. If you have, I would take it with you. If you already paid the hotel, there's no need!

However, I should take some Crowns with you, just to be sure if you need a cab or something. It can't hurt!

EDIT: as the comments states below, take the money out of the wall when you arrive! That is much cheaper than to pick it up at Schiphol.

Comment: Or get the local money out of the wall as soon as you have arrived, the cheaper option.

Comment: @Willeke is the wall a name for a currency exchange bureau or a slang for ATM/cash machine? Never seen this anywhere before...

Comment: ATM or Cash machine, (or in informal Dutch Flappentapper.) As the OP of this answer just edited it as is confirms to me that it is a common expression in Dutch. (In England it is sometimes called a 'hole in the wall'.)

Comment: Why should OP need local currency to pay for a taxi?

Comment: Hi, probably not needed indeed.

But please keep this in mind if you haven't done so. Set your card to Europe!

https://www.rabobank.nl/particulieren/betalen/service/bankpas/bankpas-gebruiken-buitenland/

Comment: The card machines will ask if you want to pay in Euros or Crowns, pick Crowns, you will get a better rate.

Answer (score 1):

Cash payments are getting less common all the time in Norway. I can't think of a single thing you might need cash for. Also taxis and public transport can be paid by card.

You should however verify your bank's fees. It is not uncommon for many banks to charge relatively high fees, either as a flat amount, a percentage or hidden as a currency exchange fee, for card usage abroad.

Comment: You might need it when buying raffle tickets or cake and coffee in a charity fair. VIPPS requires a Norwegian phone number. Not likely to be a problem though ☺️